# How to find arithmetic combination of numbers that give a particular number in python

Tags: python

I have four numbers **a**, **b**, **c**, **d** (in the source code below). And I want to get the arithmetic combination(formula) of the these numbers that gives me another number **x**, say:
 `x=12.9154769165485450430573664439479027694158016708245349917377671920719960957195046694035973.`

I have searched online and got the code below, but am not getting any formula as output.

```py
from itertools import permutations
    a=1.5931220318142209081847200718800513284478983895232845771598115094865772293425176551147041
    b=1.4180958678849065567601929430299366804279726526182465238391256914846175095759022850508064
    c=2.6859936848766770740741701602124664887178336154356167143236626569580529789903079049227949
    d=3.3917959415836179238295055450635509297663016085355811568226926449910165645921925937776673
    x=12.9154769165485450430573664439479027694158016708245349917377671920719960957195046694035973
    numbers   = ["a","b","c","d"]
    target    = x
    operators = ["+","-","*","/"]
    for values in permutations(numbers,len(numbers)):
        for oper in permutations(operators,len(numbers)-1):
            formula = "".join(o+v for o,v in zip([""]+list(oper),values))
            if eval(formula) == target: print(formula,"=",target)
```

I will greatly appreciate any help to get this done.
Thank you

Comment: Do you know it's possible, i.e. is this a quiz question or programming exercise? Without any additional integer factors? Do you really need all of that precision - I expect Python's decimal handling will cope with it, but it seems overkill to me.

Comment: I don't think it's reasonably possible with floating point values. Floating point arithmetic is inexact in computers, and your values are rounded immediately. But you can try comparing results inexactly and return the closest result.

Comment: Floating points numbers don't seem to be that exact. For example: `>>> a=1.5931220318142209081847200718800513284478983895232845771598115094865772293425176551147041`, `>>> a`, `1.593122031814221`. If you care very much about that level of precision, try to implement floating point arithmetic on strings, (or search for an existing library that does that).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend switching to something like the below:

(1) you do permutation on the operators, which means you always use ALL of them. With this numbers you will never even get close to equality using ALL arithmetic operators. I replaced it with combinations with replacement (i.e. combination allowing duplicates).

(2) IF you want to operate on floats - I would aim not for equality, but e.g. assume `0.01` error, otherwise you might run into issues not coming from maths, but from how floats are represented in python.

```py
from itertools import permutations, combinations_with_replacement
a=1.5931220318142209081847200718800513284478983895232845771598115094865772293425176551147041
b=1.4180958678849065567601929430299366804279726526182465238391256914846175095759022850508064
c=2.6859936848766770740741701602124664887178336154356167143236626569580529789903079049227949
d=3.3917959415836179238295055450635509297663016085355811568226926449910165645921925937776673
x=12.9154769165485450430573664439479027694158016708245349917377671920719960957195046694035973
numbers   = ["a","b","c","d"]
target    = x
operators = ["+","-","*","/"]
for values in permutations(numbers,len(numbers)):
    for oper in combinations_with_replacement(operators,len(numbers)-1):
        formula = "".join(o+v for o,v in zip([""]+list(oper),values))
        if abs(eval(formula) - target)<0.01: print(formula,"=",target)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no combination of these four numbers that equals x.

Floating point operations have round-off error. The code you have checks if any operations will equal x exactly, but that is highly unlikely. Instead, you should be checking if the difference is within some value of x. I changed the code to the following:

```
from itertools import permutations

a = 1.5931220318142209081847200718800513284478983895232845771598115094865772293425176551147041
b = 1.4180958678849065567601929430299366804279726526182465238391256914846175095759022850508064
c = 2.6859936848766770740741701602124664887178336154356167143236626569580529789903079049227949
d = 3.3917959415836179238295055450635509297663016085355811568226926449910165645921925937776673
x = 12.9154769165485450430573664439479027694158016708245349917377671920719960957195046694035973

EPSILON = 1
numbers = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
target = x
operators = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]

for values in permutations(numbers, len(numbers)):
    for oper in permutations(operators, len(numbers) - 1):
        formula = "".join(o + v for o, v in zip([""] + list(oper), values))
        actual = eval(formula)
        if abs(actual - target) < EPSILON:
            print(formula, "=", actual)
```

And there is no combination that evaluates to within 1 of the target.